# GCD to Linear Diophantine Equation without Euclid Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, self-learning

Is there a technique other than performing Euclid's algorithm in reverse that can elegantly show that if GCD$(a,b) = d$ then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = d$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the smallest positive integer that can be written as $ax+by$

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks.  But apparently there is a time limit on quickly an answer can be accepted so I up-voted for the moment.

Comment: @dcdo [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) for full details and conceptual elaboration.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Smallest positive integer can be a.1 + b.1 = a + b. Then?

Comment: @sud_ $x$ and $y$ don't have to be positive, just $ax+by$. If the smallest such number is $d'$, show that $d$ divides $d'$ and that $d'$ divides both $a$ and $b$. See the link in Bill's comment for more details.