# Ecclid's Lemma (Prime Divisor Property) proved by descent (as Gauss did)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm going through Elements of Number Theory by Stillwell.
One of the exercises is confusing me a bit. Finding a different proof from the normal $b = mab + npb$.

It says it's attributed to Gauss:
Show a prime $p$ cannot divide $a_1b_1$ when $a_1$,$b_1 \lt p$ 
Suppose $p$ divides $a_1b_1$ and show $p$ divides $a_1b_2$

$b_2$ = remainder when $p$ is divided by $b_1$
which gives infinite descent, which I'm not as familar with.

Then from that show if $p$ divides neither $a$ or $b$ then $p$ divides $a_1b_1$ where $a,b \lt p$

I've been trying to maybe factorise $a_1b_1 = np$

Maybe $n$ or $p = \frac{n(pq+(a_1b_1-pq)}{n}$
so $b_2 = (a_1b_1-pq)$

I'm getting lost though and going in the wrong direction I think any advice/solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it fails then there exists a $\rm\color{#c00}{minimal}$ counterexample $\,n = ab\,$ with $\,p\mid ab,\ p\nmid a,b.\ $
$\!\begin{align} \text{Necessarily  $b< p^{\phantom{|}}\!$ else} &\text{ $\,p\mid a(b\bmod p) = a(b\!-\!jp)\,$ is a $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ counterexample,}\\[.3em]
\text{therefore, we deduce}\, &\text{   $\,p\mid a(\color{#0a0}{p\bmod b}) = a(p\!-\!kb)\,$ is a $\rm\color{#c00}{smaller}$ counterexample $\color{#c00}{\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow}$}\end{align}$

**Remark** $ $ We used that $\,b' = \color{#0a0}{p\bmod b}\neq 0\,$ (by $p$ prime, $\,b>1)$. If $\,p\,$ were composite then this step may fail this way by reaching such a nontrivial factor $\,b'\,$ of $p.\,$. Similarly, in the first descent step we have employed that $\ b\bmod p\neq 0,\,$ since $\,p\nmid b\:$ by hypothesis.

The integers $\:\!n\:\!$ with $\,p\mid an\,$ are closed under subtraction, and contain $\,b,p,\,$ [so also](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) $\,\gcd(b,p).\ $ The descent in the above proof corresponds to using the Euclidean algorithm to compute the gcd (it uses a special form of the algorithm for prime argument, as explained below).

Essentially the same descent [was employed by Gauss](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) in *Disq. Arith* when he gave the first complete and rigorous proof of the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic*, i.e. existence and uniqueness of factorizations into irreducibles (primes). As explained in that linked post, when interpreted constructively this yields an algorithm for computing inverses $\!\bmod p.\, $ See also below, from a [deleted thread.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34557/242)

---

To compute inverses modulo a *prime* $\,p,\,$ rather than use the full-blown extended Euclidean algorithm, it is conceptually simpler to use a special case that goes back to Gauss (*Disq. Arith. Art.5*, 1801). The idea is so simple that it can be taught to bright grade school students. Namely, to compute the fraction $\ 1/b\pmod{\! p}\ $ we repeatedly scale the numerator and denominator in a way that reduces the value of the denominator $\!\bmod p,\,$ i.e. scale $\, a/b\to an/bn\ $ by the least $\,n\,$ such that $\,bn > p\,.\,$ For example, modulo $29$

$$ \frac{1}8\ \to\ \frac{4}{32}\ \equiv\ \frac{4}{3}\ \to\ \frac{40}{30}\ \equiv\ \frac{11}{1}\pmod{\!29}$$
Because each step reduces the denominator, eventually we must reach a denominator of $1$ (not $0$ else we would have $\,bn = p\,$ so $\,b>1\,$ would be a proper factor of the prime $\,p\,$). The algorithm has a vivid interpretation in terms of "clock arithmetic" on a clock face of $\,p\,$ minutes. Namely the reduction step is simply: starting at $\,0,\,$ take $\,n\,$ steps of size $\,b\,$ until you cycle, passing $0\,$ and landing in the interval $[0,b-1].\,$ You can't land on $0\,$ else $ b$ would properly divide $\,p.\,$ Now do the same to this smaller multiple of $\,b.\,$ Each loop around the clock face produces a smaller multiple of $\,b,\,$ so eventually it reaches the multiple $1$. This graphical formulation goes over quite well with bright grade-school students (esp. when enhanced  by visual aids, e.g. periodical curves such as Roulettes (Spirograph curves), Star Polygons - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3253030/242)).

From this one quickly infers that irreducible integers $\,p\,$ are prime, i.e. $\,p\ |\ a\,b\ \Rightarrow\ p\ |\ a\ \ {\rm or}\ \ p\ |\ b\,.\,$ This is essentially the way that Gauss constructed the first known proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, i.e. unique factorization of integers.

Note that this iterates $\,(b,\,p)\to (p\bmod b,\,p)\,$ vs. $\,(b,\,p)\to (p\bmod b,\, b)\,$ in the Euclidean algorithm. It may fail for *composite* moduli.

As for *uniqueness* of inverses $\,a,\,a'\,$ of $\,b,\ $  hint: $\ a\ =\ a\,(b\,a') \ =\ (a\,b)\,a'\, =\ a'$

Comment: Thanks, this is along the line I was thinking of, using subtraction, gcd and the smallest example. It was just getting it into the notation they were using was throwing me off a bit into overcomplicating it. Would you be able to put it into that form of $a_1b_2$ etc?

Comment: @GloriosoTom $ $ Your $b_2$ is $\,p\bmod b_1,\,$ which is *nonzero* since $\,b_1\nmid p,\,$ by $\,1< b_1 < p\,$ and $p$ prime.