# Does the equation $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(ax+by,b)=\gcd(a,ax+by)$ hold for $a, b, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Does the equation $ax + by = \gcd(a, b) = \gcd(ax+by,b) = \gcd(a,ax+by)$ hold for $a, b, x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$?  (Note that $x$ and $y$ are not uniquely determined by the equation $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$.)

From this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203383), I have the result $\gcd(a,b)=ax'+by'=c$.  So I guess my main inquiry would then be:  Can I push this finding further into
$$\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c) = \gcd(a,b) = c?$$

If not, under what conditions will such a system of equations hold?

Comment: No.    Try $a=2,b=3,x=3,y=0$

Comment: By Euclid $\,(ax+by,b) = (ax,b).\,$ Why do you think $\,(ax,b) = (a,b)?\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, I am looking for conditions under which the following equation holds:
$$\gcd(\gcd(a,b),a)=\gcd(\gcd(a,b),b)=\gcd(a,b).$$

Comment: @lulu, your counterexample is an actually an instance where my equation holds.

Comment: Recall that in the equation $\gcd(a,b) = ax' + by'$, $x', y' \in \mathbb{Z}$ are *not unique*.

Comment: @Jose Ah, your question was not clear. Yes, you could use Bezout to prove that, but it is easier to use the GCD Distributive Law, viz. $\, d=(a,b)\mid a\,$ so $\,(d,a) = d(1,a/d) = d.\,$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) for a handful of proofs of the distributive law (including one by Bezout).

Comment: Thanks for illuminating me, @BillDubuque.  I was thinking of a proof along exactly the same lines as you did, but could not get to articulate it properly.  Your advice to use the GCD Distributive Law is very apt for this case.

Comment: @Jose Alternatively: if $d\mid a\,$ then $\,c\mid d,a\iff c\mid d,\,$ so $\,d,a\,$ and $\,d\,$ have the same set $\,C\,$ of *common* divisors $\,c\,$ so they have the same *greatest* common divisor $(= \max C)$ $\ \ $

Comment: @Jose Or, by Euclid $\, (d,a) = (d,\,a\bmod d) = (d,0) = d.\ $ There are *many* ways to prove it.

Comment: Or $\ ((a,b),b) = (a,(b,b)) = (a,b)\ $ by the [GCD associative law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/242) in the comments, the equation
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,\gcd(a,b))=\gcd(b,\gcd(a,b))$$
can be proved using the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242).