# Proving Bezout's Identity with Cosets of $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This wonderful restatement was taken from Keith Conrad's notes: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicgp.pdf?fbclid=IwAR2Tve3QPGsIEZAfj5sVhoKDdhXT2oPMsSnGoKyhZGc1NxFcynmk1_uJNRE

Theorem: $\forall a,b\Bbb{Z}$, we have $a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}=\gcd(a,b)\Bbb{Z}$.

Proof attempt: If $\gcd(a,b)=d$, then $a=\alpha\cdot d$ and $b=\beta\cdot d$ such that $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$. Thus, $a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}=\alpha\cdot d\Bbb{Z}+ \beta\cdot d\Bbb{Z}=(\alpha+\beta)d\Bbb{Z}$. Since $(\alpha +\beta)\in\Bbb{Z}$ implies $(\alpha+\beta)d\in d\Bbb{Z}$. By properties of cosets, $(\alpha+\beta)d\Bbb{Z}=d\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: The simple proof is already fully presented there (Theorem A.1 p. 8). Did you not understand it?  This is a standard result that will become clearer when you study ideal theory of rings.

Comment: Remark the Conrad's claim that "The proof here is completely independent of Euclid’s algorithm" is a bit misleading in my opinion. The proof he gives uses the fact that subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic, whose proof uses the (Euclidean) Division Algorithm - which is precisely the inductuve / descent step in Euclid's algorithm. It's the group-theoretic form of the proof I [give here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) in more elementary language.

Comment: @BillDubuque:I did not understand his proof. I don't see why $c$ being a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ implies $c\in a\Bbb{Z}+b\Bbb{Z}$. I also find it amusing that using the fact subgroups of a cylic group is cyclic makes the proof cylic.

Comment: I think I get it now. nevermind. lol.