# Can $\Bbb Z_n$l ideals be generated by one element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let's define the ring, $\Bbb Z_n$ (It is surely a well-known ring.)

1. set :  $Z_n$ ={$[0]_{n}$, $[1]_{n}$, ... $[n-1]_{n} \}$
2. operation : addition or multiplication for the $mod n$

Say the $m \in \Bbb Z_n$, It is obvious that $\langle m \rangle$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z_n$.

Then, $\forall$ ideal **J** of the $Z_n$,
 can the ideal **J** be expressed as the $\langle m \rangle$ ?

Comment: Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I caught it.

Comment: What is "the **J**"?

Comment: If  said result on cyclic groups is unfamiliar then you can instead use the same [one-line proof as in $\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) to show that every ideal $\neq 0$  is generated by its least positive element.

Comment: @BillDubuque Which elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ are "positive"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich As in the OP we presume the standard nonnegative reps $\,0,1,\ldots, n\!-\!1\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $I\subset \mathbb{Z}_n$ be ideal.Let $\eta:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_n$ be natural projection then observe  $\eta^{-1}(I)$ is ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. So it is generated by a single element (say a) as $\mathbb{Z}$ being PID. Now it is easy to see $I$ is generated by $\eta(a)$.

Answer (score -1):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_n\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle n\rangle}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, we have $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is also a PID.

Comment: This is incorrect. Being a PID includes (as the name suggests) being a domain.

Comment: Not to mention it is almost surely beyond the OP's knowledge level.