# If $c\ge b\ge a$ and $c\mid a^2,b^2$, and $a$ is the minimal number satisfy $c\mid a^2$, does $a$ necessarily divide $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, square-numbers

Assume $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive numbers, $a  \le b$ and $b  \le c$.

If $a^2\equiv0\pmod c$ and $b^2\equiv0\pmod c$, and $a$ is the minimal number satisfy $a^2\equiv0\pmod c$, do we always have $a\mid b$?

Comment: Updated the question, sorry, forgot to mention that $a$ is the minimal number that satisfy the condition

Comment: Hint: the set of square multiples of $c$ is *closed under gcd*: $c\mid a^2,b^2\Rightarrow c\mid\gcd(a^2,b^2)\!=\!\gcd(a,b)^2,\,$ so classical Euclidean / gcd descent applies as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242) in the dupe, i.e. if $\,a\nmid b\,$ then $\gcd(a,b) < a\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,b)^2< a^2$ contra minimality of $\,a.\ \ $

Comment: @wddd I deleted my comment giving the smallest counterexample to your prior version, but the rest seems still relevant: "for next time, please read [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) (show some work), and use a more descriptive title".